# Anchor Link Offset doesn't work ONLY on the first click

Tags: javascript

Below is my JS code. I have a page with anchor links scrolling. I need the user to go to a specific section on the page when the link is clicked, without covering the basic heading of the section.

Here's what I have been able to accomplish (of course, with a bit of help from Stackoverlfow sleuthing).

```
// The function actually applying the offset
function offsetAnchor() {
    if(location.hash.length !== 0) {
        window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 100);
    }
}

// This will capture hash changes while on the page
window.addEventListener("hashchange", offsetAnchor);

// This is here so that when you enter the page with a hash,
// it can provide the offset in that case too. Having a timeout
// seems necessary to allow the browser to jump to the anchor first.
window.setTimeout(offsetAnchor, 1); // The delay of 1 is arbitrary and may not always work right (although it did in my testing).
```

The above code seems to work, but the problem is it works only from the second time I click any anchor. Why doesn't it fire on the first tie itself? I know it is related to hashchange, so the javascript is picking up from the second links onwards only because there is a hashchange. Can you give me a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function () {
  function offsetAnchor() {
    if (location.hash.length !== 0) {
      window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY - 100);
    }
  }

  // This will capture hash changes while on the page
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", offsetAnchor);

  // This is here so that when you enter the page with a hash,
  // it can provide the offset in that case too. Having a timeout
  // seems necessary to allow the browser to jump to the anchor first.
  window.setTimeout(offsetAnchor, 1); // The delay of 1 is arbitrary and m
};
```

```html
<a href="#hello">Hello</a>
<div style="height: 300px;background:#ccc">spacer</div>
<div id="hello">Hello there!</div>
<div style="height: 300px;background:#ccc">spacer</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You just nailed it so hard and made my weekend happy :)